# Set Custom Theme in Fullscreen DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, android-dialogfragment

i implemented Dark theme in my Application. But i have problem to customize my full screen dialog. When i try to set theme it doesn't affect the dialog screen.

Here is my styles.xml

```xml
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorSecondary</item
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorDanger</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

My dialog fragment layout

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
            app:title="Add New"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
...
```

Then i set the style in onCreate function

```kotlin
class AddNewFinanceDialogFragment : DialogFragment(), OnTimeSelectedListener {
    private lateinit var financeViewModel: FinanceViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogTheme)
        initViewModel()
    }
...
```

[image: Dialog Background still transparent and style is not applied]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog">
    <item name="dialogTheme">@style/my_dialogTheme</item>
</style>
<style name="my_dialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.